# Error when calling a PostgreSql stored procedure returning a bigint

Tags: sql, node.js, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.2

I have created a PostgreSql stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "MySchema".UserAccountInsert(
    id             bigint,
    lang           varchar(3),
    nname           varchar(40),
    email          varchar(40),
    email_conf     boolean,
    status         smallint,
    status_update  bigint,
    creation       bigint,
    preferences    json)
    RETURNS bigint AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    ...
BEGIN
    ...
    RETURN ret_id;
END; $BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am trying to call it from pgAdmin III with the following statement;

```
SELECT * from "MySchema".UserAccountInsert(
1000,"ENG","name1000","email1000","f",1,1391878008121,1391878008121,"{}");
```

But I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "ENG" does not exist
LINE 36: SELECT * from "MySchema".UserAccountInsert(1000,"ENG","name1...
```

What is the right way to call this procedure? Eventually, it will be called from Node's PG module, so I am looking for the proper query statement. Thanks.

Comment: String literals have to be put between single quotes. Use `'ENG'` not `"ENG"`. More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS and you should call the function like this: `select UserAccountInsert(..)`, not `select * from ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has disappeared with the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT "MySchema".UserAccountInsert(
    1000::bigint,
    'ENG'::varchar(3),
    'name1000'::varchar(40),
    'email1000'::varchar(40),
    'f'::boolean,
    1::smallint,
    1391878008121::bigint,
    1391878008121::bigint,
    '{}'::json);
```

but I am getting another error message. I am creating another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21650174/error-query-has-no-destination-for-result-data-for-function-returning-a-bigint).