# INSERT INTO error: no destination for result data

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

For the following function, I get an error:
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "registration" line 19 at SQL statement

The error refers to the insert statement (when I comment it out the error goes away) and I have no idea what it is trying to tell me.

Can someone help?  Thanks.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION registration( wr text ) RETURNS integer AS $rL$
DECLARE
    eml text;
    pwd text;
    emid integer;
    rowt Email%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    eml := getWebVarValue( wr , 'email' );
    select * into rowt from Email where email_email = eml;
    if rowt IS NOT NULL THEN
       RAISE EXCEPTION 'email address, %, already registered.' , eml;
    END IF;
    pwd := getWebVarValue( wr , 'password' );
    if pwd is null then
       RAISE EXCEPTION 'No password specified in registration.';
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO Email VALUES (eml,pwd) RETURNING Email.email_id as emid;
    RETURN emid;
END;
$rL$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Email.email_id is declared as:
email_id integer DEFAULT nextval('email_email_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,

Comment: Could you try tp store the result of the SELECT statement? Similar question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21650174/error-query-has-no-destination-for-result-data-for-function-returning-a-bigint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [proper syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) is:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (things)
RETURNING some.expression
INTO variable_name;
```

You used `AS` instead of `INTO`.